# How can I resume training pl.Trainer after interruption?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I have Model and Trainer pytorch-lightning objects which are initialized as follows:

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join('experiments', experiment_name, '{epoch}-{avg_valid_iou:.4f}'),
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor='avg_valid_iou',
    mode='max',
    prefix=''
)
model = nn.DataParallel (FaultNetPL(batch_size=5)).cuda()
trainer = Trainer( checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback, 
                  max_epochs=500,gpus=1,
                  logger=logger)
```

Then I start training using:

```
trainer.fit(model)
```

But  training was interrupted and now I would like to resume it using checkpoint from N-th iteration
So i tried initialize model and trainer as:

```
model = FaultNetPL.load_from_checkpoint('experiments/VNET/epoch=77-avg_valid_iou=0.7604.ckpt',batch_size=5)
trainer = Trainer(resume_from_checkpoint = 'epoch=77-avg_valid_iou=0.7604.ckpt', 
                  checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback, 
                  max_epochs=500,gpus=1,
                  logger=logger)
```

But again and again training starting from scratch (from 0th epoch and huge error). What did I miss?